# How would I make a search view display results in a new page instead of on the same page?

Tags: views, search

I have view (a block) that searches my products for various fields such as sell price, title, ect. It works except all the search results appear right in that block instead of on a new page. Here is an example of what I want to do: http://www.themesdojo.com/drupads/

Comment: It would be better if you explain more details about the new page and what is missing in the new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show your exposed views filter as a block, and place the block on your search page, then all submissions will show results on your view page.

Under the advanced field-set in the views UI, once you have created an exposed filter, an option will appear under the EXPOSED FORM heading that will allow you to create a block.

You can see an example of a front page search leading to a views results page here... http://www.myweddingfayre.com

Comment: So does my product search view need to be a page then and not a block?

Comment: Yeah, I would create the view as a page, then expose the filter as a block, and through Structure > Blocks, place the block on a separate page.